# No qualifying bean of type available - expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm roughly following the code in Spring In Action, 5th ed. Currently running into a problem autowiring a bean, and I can't seem to figure out why the bean isn't available in the running context. Here are some of the relevant classes:

Controller where the `UserRepository` bean is expected:

```
package tacos.web;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import tacos.data.jpa.UserRepository;
import tacos.security.RegistrationForm;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public RegistrationController(
            UserRepository userRepo, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String registerForm() {
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processRegistration(RegistrationForm form) {
        userRepo.save(form.toUser(passwordEncoder));
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

}
```

The `UserRepository` JPA interface:

```
package tacos.data.jpa;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import tacos.security.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

The `User` class:

```
package tacos.security;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String fullname;
    private final String street;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final String zip;
    private final String phoneNumber;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The main class:

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    }
}
```

The error itself:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationController' defined in file: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tacos.data.jpa.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Not quite sure why the `UserRepository` bean isn't being wired correctly. I have other classes in my project where the bean wiring happens correctly.

Happy to include any other classes needed to understand why I'm seeing this error.

Comment: Do you have repository scanning enabled in sprint configurations?

Comment: Please share your config. Devil is in the details.

Comment: @SSC Repository scanning should be enabled by the fact that the class with my main method has the `@SpringBootAnnotation` on it, which should scan for components in all sub-packages.

Comment: @yousafsajjad Happy to share it. Which config are you referring to in this case?

Comment: I was referring to the datasourceConfig where you might have added annotation: 
    EnableJpaRepositories
    ComponentScan

Comment: I believe the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation isn't necessary if you have Spring Data JPA on the classpath, which I do.

Answer (score 1):

Try below points

1. Please check package structure that spring boot able to scan your repository class or not.
2. Also check your User class should be annotated with @Entity.

Comment: I've added the `User` and main class to the post. The `User` class does have the `@Entity` annotation, and the main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which should mean all components in any sub-packages should be picked up by Spring Boot.

Comment: @Pastafarian try to autowired UserRepository  in your controller

Comment: As of Spring 4.3, you no longer need the `@Autowired` annotation to inject beans. Constructor injection is now the preferred method. See [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300706/dependency-injection-field-injection-vs-constructor-injection)